# use of "system font" on recent MacOS failing

Tags: osx, fonts

With `emacs-version` = 27.2, and on MacOS 12.2.1, attempts to do something like

```
(set-fontset-font t '(#x2070 . #x209C) "System Font" nil 'prepend)
```

are causing error logs to the terminal where I started emacs along the lines of :

```
2022-02-24 11:08:02.324 Emacs-arm64-12[63182:4750483] CoreText note: Client requested
name ".SFNS-UltraCompressedLightG4", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended
font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as 
CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
```

(I've inserted newlines in the above to make it easier to read; really it's all on one line.)
There are a slew of such lines, with variations in the name of the requested `".SFNS-.."`.

Is Emacs using the wrong system calls in its use of the font, and is there a workaround?

**More details:**

```
;; ; superscripts and subscripts: ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰ ₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₀ ₘₙₚᵣₛₜₜ
(set-fontset-font t '(#x2070 . #x209C) "System Font" nil 'prepend)
```

I know from having cut and pasted the comment text into TextEdit that System Font is indeed capable of rendering all of the subscripts.  If I start my Emacs with `-q` (*via* `/Applications/Emacs/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -q`) and paste the above into my `*scratch*` buffer, I do not see the subscripts in whatever font Emacs takes as its default.  If I then `C-x C-e` just the `set-fontset-font` line, which should get those characters rendered, they stay invisible, and I get the error messages on the Terminal.

Comment: _worksforme_. emacs 27.2 from https://emacsformacosx.com/ installed via `brew cask`

Comment: Hmm.  My emacs is also just from emacsformacosx.  I'll have to check a very vanilla `-q` startup

Comment: And are you on 12.2.1?

Comment: yes. i repeated your second test (with and w/o `-q`) and it fails for me too. smells like Emacs is using a deprecated API. Menlo couldn't handle any of the subscripted letters other than `r`.

Comment: same results w/ HEAD

Comment: Also fails with emacs 28.2 and macOS 12.6

Comment: Now reported as bug: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=58328